# Slugs not working in Forms with GET method

Tags: symfony, routes

This is my routing:

```
myapp_upgradeAccount:
    path:  /upgradeAccount
    defaults: { _controller: myapp:UpgradeAccount:index }

myapp_checkUsernameForUpgrade:
    path: /upgradeAccount/check/{username}
    defaults: { _controller: myapp:UpgradeAccount:checkUsername }
    methods: [GET]
```

and this is my form

```
<form method="get" action="upgradeAccount/check">
    <label for="username">Insert your username:</label>
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <input id="chech-username-for-upgrade" class="green" type="submit" value="Check">
    ...
```

But everytime I submit the form I get this error:

```
No route found for "GET /upgradeAccount/check"
```

The problem is that when I submit the form, I get the following URL:

`http://localhost/app_dev.php/upgradeAccount/check?username=123`

when i think I should be getting

`http://localhost/app_dev.php/upgradeAccount/check/123`

If I trz the latter manually, it works allright. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way HTML forms work.
From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1):

> get: With the HTTP "get" method, the form data set is appended to the
>   URI specified by the action attribute (with a question-mark ("?") as
>   separator) and this new URI is sent to the processing agent.

To do what you want to do keeping the `GET` method, you have to define your route as:

```
myapp_checkUsernameForUpgrade:
    path: /upgradeAccount/check
    defaults: { _controller: myapp:UpgradeAccount:checkUsername }
    methods: [GET]
```

And in your controller, you access the query string parameter with:

```
if(!is_null($this->getRequest()->get('username'))
{
  //Do your stuff
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want your user to be redirected to a url formatted as `upgradeAccount/check/{username}`, you can either do it with JavaScript (as suggested in @usoban answer) or inside the controller using `Redirect`:

```
//path:  /upgradeAccount/check
public function check()
{
  if(!is_null($this->get('request')->request->get('username')))
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('myapp_checkUsernameForUpgrade', array('username' => $this->get('request')->request->get('username'))));

  //By default, return the view with your form asking the username
  return $this->render('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.twig');
}

//path: /upgradeAccount/check/{username}
public function checkUsername($username)
{
  //Do some fun stuff with $username coming from the url
}
```

Then in your view, the form signatures becomes:

```
<form method="post" action="upgradeAccount/check">
  <label for="username">Insert your username:</label>
  <input name="username" type="text">
  <!-- additionnal fields -->
  <input id="chech-username-for-upgrade" class="green" type="submit" value="Check">
</form>
```

And your route:

```
myapp_check:
    path: /upgradeAccount/check
    defaults: { _controller: myapp:UpgradeAccount:check }
    methods: [POST]
myapp_checkUsernameForUpgrade:
    path: /upgradeAccount/check/{username}
    defaults: { _controller: myapp:UpgradeAccount:checkUsername }
    methods: [GET]
```

Comment: THe problem is that I want to have uniques URLS for every user, as my routing shows

Comment: What is the process? You want users to write their username in an input and when they click a button it goes to `upgradeAccount/check/{username}`?

Comment: I have updated my answer. 2 things: I would use a JS solution as suggested by @usoban and as a fallback, the controller redirect. Note that this would be cleaner using the symfony `FormBuilder` instead of doing it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate routes that take parameters.
so you would need to do

```
<form method="get" action="{{path('your_route_name', {username:'usernmae'})">
```

However this obviously won't quite work for you since you do not know the username until they enter it. You could look into the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) but this will require javascript. Not the best solution, but it will work. Otherwise you will need to remove the username parameter

Answer (score 0):

As @cheesemacfly mentioned, that is how forms work :)

To get it woking myself, I used some javascript. Let's assume you're using jQuery:

```
<form method="get" action="upgradeAccount/check/___username___" id="my_form">
...
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my_form').submit(function(evt){
      var username = $('#username').val(),   
          action   = $(this).attr('action').replace(/___username___/g, username);

      if (/* empty or whatever 'validation' */) {
        evt.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting
        return false;
      }      

      $(this).attr('action', action);
      return true;
  });
});
```